# Bootstrap modal is closed on button click/form submission

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I open a modal on Login button click. I have an other button inside the modal which onclick will hide a div. But as soon as I click on the button the modal will close. Then again on Login button click the modal will show up with hide div. I don't want the modal to close. Please help. Am new to bootstrap

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="BPA" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog ">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" >&times;</button>
                   <br /> <h4>Sign In</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class=" row">
                      <form id="Form1" runat="server">
                        <div class="col-md-4">


      <div runat="server" id="hide"> 

  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>                       
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtUname1" runat="server"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter your username"></asp:TextBox>
  <label  for="exampleInputEmail1" >Password</label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtPwd1" TextMode="Password" runat="server"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter password" ></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSignin" class="btn btn-primary btn-block shadow" runat="server" Text="Sign in" OnClick="btnSignin_click" />   
    <asp:Label ID="errorLbl" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger"></asp:Label>

      </div>


      <div runat="server" id="Recoveremail" Visible="false"> 

  <label  for="exampleInputEmail1" >Enter your Email address</label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="Txtemail"  runat="server"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter email address" ></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="Txtrecovery" class="btn btn-primary btn-block shadow" runat="server" data-target="#BPA" data-toggle="modal" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnRecoverSubmit_Click" /> 
    <label id="lbltxt" runat="server"></label>

      </div>  

         <asp:Label ID="Upwd" runat="server" Text="Forgot"></asp:Label>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" type="button" runat="server" Text="Password?" OnClick="btnPwdSubmit_Click"/>

                               </div>
                          </form>
                    </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you please add fiddle link ?

Comment: You are using asp controls in the modal which is running server methods onclick. The model is javascript generated and its state is lost on every postback the asp controls performs.

Comment: yes. What can I do to solve this